# "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" Error in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and am following a course.
I ran across this error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {   
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle") 
        {
            Debug.Log("We hit an obstacle!");
            movement.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone clarify to me what this means?

Comment: next time, google the error message, find out the difference between a C# statement and a C# expression. Then all you need to do is to find a line that contains something that is not a statement. that's the only way to learn. you can even do it without research if you find a line that is neither an assignment, a call, an increment, a decrement, await or a new object expression. you just need to read the error message. you just need to short-circuit your "oh got error -> stackoverflow" instinct

Comment: @Piglet I tried to google it but couldn't find anything since I've never written code in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expression is not a statement. It cannot be on its own.

`FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame`

You're missing something here.

`FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame()` is probably correct.

Also you should make sure that FindObjectOfType actually returns a GameManager instance, not null befor you invoke any methods or you'll cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame;
```

Does your GameManager script have EndGame public variable or function?
If that is function, you missed (). So you can write like below;

```
FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
```

If that is public variable, you must assign it to the variable like this;

```
variable = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame;
```